# iOS 7 Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Tags: ios7, crash

Does anyone have a clue on this crash ?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Triggered by Thread:  0


Last Exception Backtrace:

0   CoreFoundation                  0x30e57e83 __exceptionPreprocess + 131

1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b1b86c7 objc_exception_throw + 38

2   CoreFoundation                  0x30e57dc5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 112

3   CoreData                        0x30bc6be3 -[_PFBatchFaultingArray objectAtIndex:] + 
146

4   ChevronRetail                   0x000345bd 0x1f000 + 87485

5   ChevronRetail                   0x000314e5 0x1f000 + 74981

6   ChevronRetail                   0x0003143d 0x1f000 + 74813

7   ChevronRetail                   0x000313c3 0x1f000 + 74691

8   ChevronRetail                   0x00031cc7 0x1f000 + 76999

9   UIKit                           0x336d7349 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) 
_delegateScrollViewAnimationEnded] + 68

10  UIKit                           0x336d72c5 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) 
_scrollViewAnimationEnded:finished:] + 176

11  UIKit                           0x023c001b 0x2393000 + 184347

12  UIKit                           0x3377fd6b -[UIAnimator stopAnimation:] + 466

13  UIKit                           0x3377f74d -[UIAnimator(Static) _advanceAnimationsOfType:withTimestamp:] + 284

14  UIKit                           0x3377f62d -[UIAnimator(Static) _LCDHeartbeatCallback:] + 52

15  QuartzCore                      0x332b2ad3 CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 98

16  QuartzCore                      0x332b287d CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 344

17  IOMobileFramebuffer             0x35edc76d IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 104

18  IOKit                           0x31b39be5 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 248

19  CoreFoundation                  0x30e17b81 __CFMachPortPerform + 136

20  CoreFoundation                  0x30e22777 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34

21  CoreFoundation                  0x30e22713 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 346

22  CoreFoundation                  0x30e20edf __CFRunLoopRun + 1406

23  CoreFoundation                  0x30d8b471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524

24  CoreFoundation                  0x30d8b253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106

25  GraphicsServices                0x35abf2eb GSEventRunModal + 138

26  UIKit                           0x33640845 UIApplicationMain + 1136

27  ChevronRetail                   0x00057fd5 0x1f000 + 233429

28  libdyld.dylib                   0x3b6b1ab7 start + 2


Thread 0 Crashed:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b7681fc __pthread_kill + 8

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b7cfa4f pthread_kill + 55

2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b719029 abort + 73

3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ab6798b abort_message + 71

4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ab806e3 default_terminate_handler() + 251

5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b1b8937 _objc_terminate() + 191

6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ab7e1b1 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 77

7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ab7dd13 __cxa_rethrow + 99

8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b1b880b objc_exception_rethrow + 39

9   CoreFoundation                  0x30d8b4e3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 639

10  CoreFoundation                  0x30d8b24f CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103

11  GraphicsServices                0x35abf2e7 GSEventRunModal + 135

12  UIKit                           0x33640841 UIApplicationMain + 1133

13  ChevronRetail                   0x00057fd1 0x1f000 + 233425

14  libdyld.dylib                   0x3b6b1ab5 start + 1
```